# Cordova error: network_err: xmlhttprequest exception 101

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

Ok, so I have looked at every question for this, my issue is that when I run my Cordova app on the iOS emulator, My ajax calls are not working and are returning this error: error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Now, I have read all about the cross origin issues but that is not my case, I have my server headers to accept any origin and have already tested the ajax call on multiple different web servers and all are able to run just fine. I have used ajax in many cordova apps and have never run into this before, can anyone give me some insight on why this might be happening?

I have used ajax calls with both async false and true before, this time, when I use false I get that network error, if I use true, I just get an error, no specifics.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         url: 'https://api.domain.com/put/add_user/?api_key=<api_key>',
         data: {device_id: 'jhbdjhcbhjdbchsdnjkcdhsjbcd'},
         success: function(data){
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         },
         error: function(data){
           alert(JSON.stringify(data));
         }
       });
```